# Query Dataverse audit logs from Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, audit-logging, dataverse

I'm very new to this so forgive me

We have a requirement `Every X days, query changes made in tables/records in dataverse and send email with these changes`

From what I've worked out, this could be done with Power Automate, so every 7 days run a HTTP trigger that triggers a C# function which queries the audit logs and sends an email with a table of things that have changed.

I have audit logging working in my test environment and it shows changes made to a table, it's just the rest I'm unsure about.

The main bit I'm stuck with is how do I query the dataverse audit logs from a C# Azure Function app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using an Azure Function

You could perform a HTTP request to the Dataverse web API using the `audits` entity set name. The request would look something like:

```
GET /api/data/v9.2/audits HTTP/1.1
Host: {organizationUniqueName}.{region}.dynamics.com
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAi...
```

Note, you need to provide a bearer authentication token in the request (See [Use OAuth authentication with Microsoft Dataverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-oauth%5D(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-data-web-api)) for details on how to do that. See [Query data using the Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-data-web-api) for a comprehensive guide on querying the Dataverse web API.

Alternatively, you could use either one of the below NuGet packages to query Dataverse using C#.

1. [Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies/) (Only works with Azure Function runtime 1.x)
2. [Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client/) (Public preview. Works with runtime 2.x+)

Regardles of the package you choose to use, the C# code will look more or less the same with the exception of `ServiceClient` being applicable to the second NuGet package, and `CrmServiceClient` applying to the first package.

```cs
var client = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);

var auditLogsQuery =
    @"<fetch top='50' >
        <entity name='audit' >
            <filter>
            <condition attribute='operation' operator='eq' value='1' />
            <condition attribute='createdon' operator='last-x-hours' value='1' />
            </filter>
        </entity>
    </fetch>";

EntityCollection auditLogs = client.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(auditLogsQuery));
```

## Using Power Automate

Seeing as you have mentioned the use of Power Automate, I suggest you consider using it to meet your requirements. Querying data in Dataverse is native to Power Automate through the built-in Dataverse connector.

Lets say you have the below [Fetch XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/use-fetchxml-construct-query) query to pull back all audit logs where the operation was `Create` (1) and the operations were performed in the last hour.

> Tip: You can use the [FetchXML Builder](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/Cinteros.Xrm.FetchXmlBuilder/) plugin in the [XrmToolBox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/) to author these queries. Querying the audit logs in the advanced find is not supported.

```xml
<fetch top="50" >
  <entity name="audit" >
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="operation" operator="eq" value="1" />
      <condition attribute="createdon" operator="last-x-hours" value="1" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Using the Dataverse `List rows` action, you can specify you want to query the `Audits` table and provide the above Fetch XML query in the `Fetch Xml Query` property of the action. See below for an example:

[image]

The results of this query are now available throughout the Power Automate cloud flow. For example, here I am using the `Compose` action to write out the `Operation`, `Record Type`, `Record ID`, and `Changed Field` for the returned audit logs.

[image]